# Refer to Vue instance from another element instance

Tags: javascript, vue.js, leaflet

I have created a leaflet map with vue.js. I have a method named 'showSubmit, which is to be called at leaflet marker moveend event. This is what I am doing:

```
this.map.markers.user.on("moveend", function(e) {
    this.showSubmit(e);
});
```

However, this call is showing error, as '**this**' within the function refers to the leaflet map instance and not the vue instance. As a workaround, I have declared a variable, like this:

```
var $this = this;
this.map.markers.user.on("moveend", function(e) {
        $this.showSubmit(e, $this);
});
```

Although this works, but I want to avoid this approach. How can I access the vue component from within leaflet map instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use ES6 features, than [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) will help, they dont change this.

```
this.map.markers.user.on("moveend", (e) => {
    this.showSubmit(e);
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `.on("moveend", (e) => {...})` ?

Comment: @nikoshr oh, sure, u are right :) Thats what u get when dont pay enough attention

Answer (score 2):

Bind **this** instance like the following -

```
this.map.markers.user.on("moveend", function(e) {
  this.showSubmit(e);
}.bind(this));
```